# How to undo deletion of an excel sheet

Tags: excel

English may not sound natural using a translator. sorry. Going to the main topic, while working on Excel, I accidentally deleted a sheet from Excel and threw it away. Is there any way I can turn it around? I've learned that I can never turn back. I have already saved.

Tried to undo such as control + z. just didn't come back.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is to open your backup copy of the spreadsheet.

When doing important tasks I always work on a copy - if the next step or process is successful then I make another copy. This way I have a "set" of copies being the historical backup.

Excel does warn you about the consequence of deleting a, or several, sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel file is saved on OneDrive (or any other cloud) or Sharepoint, you can open an old version of the file and transfer the sheet to your recent file.

If you have saved it on your hard drive and your computer is set up to save backups you can right click the file, open the options menu. There you might then see a list of past versions, from  which you can get back your sheet.

[image]